# Redirect a user to another page from the URL parameters

Tags: jquery, html, redirect

We have SSO enabled across our 2 sites on different platforms, Site A and Site B. SSO works fine when I navigate from the link called Site B from Site A and vice versa, but it does not work when I click on a link of another page of Site B from Site A, i.e.

Site A --> Site B **Works**
Site A --> Site B.some_page **Doesn't work**

*I need this to work as we have a direct link to this page in Site A.*

I have to go like this in order to go to some_page in Site B, i.e.

Site A --> Site B --> Site B.some_page

I don't have the access to the SSO setup, so what I am thinking of having is a self redirect in place, that when a user clicks the link Site B.some_page on Site A, it take the user to Site B(which will log them in) and the redirect it to next page, Site B.some_page

So, 
Site A --> Site B(redirects after 1 sec) --> Site B.some_page **this should be the redirect**

Can this be done like passing some parameters also in the URL to redirect them?

Comment: Yes, this can be done by passing parameters as you suggest. Do you have access to modify the code for Site B?

Comment: Yes, I have the code access to site B and Site A as well, just that the SSO is setup by 3rd party on the backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Here's a URL example.

http://example.com/page.html?rd001

Then, assuming you need to use JavaScript, you can check for the redirect flag and run a redirect.

```
<script>
$(function() {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf('rd001') > -1) {
        window.location = 'http://example2.com/page2.html';
    }
});
</script>
```